# Pass class as a parameter to method

Tags: c#, class, parameters

I'm having trouble finishing this method. How can I pass class as parameter and return the same class? 
This is the scenario I've met

```
Class A
{
...
}

Class C
{
 ....
}

Class B
{
  A a = getJSONClass(String jsonString, classA?);
  C c = getJSONClass(String jsonString, classC?);

  public (class?) getJSONClass(String jsonString, class?)
  {
   MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
   DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(class?.type);
   return ser.ReadObject(memoryStream) as class?;
  }

}
```

Any help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well syntactically you'd use generics:

```
public T getJSONClass<T>(String jsonString) where T : class
{
   MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
   DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
   return ser.ReadObject(memoryStream) as T;
}
```

usage:

```
A a = getJSONClass<A>(String jsonString);
C c = getJSONClass<C>(String jsonString);
```

Comment: I think you'd need a `class` constraint on `T` to use `as T`? (but +1 none the less).

Answer (score 1):

Use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
    public T GetDeserializedObject<T>(string jsonString) where T: class
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)))
        {
            return serializer.ReadObject(stream) as T;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do something like:

```
Class A
{
...
}

Class C
{
 ....
}

Class B
{
  A a = (A)getJSONClass(String jsonString, typeof(A));
  C c = (C)getJSONClass(String jsonString, typeof(C));

  public object getJSONClass(String jsonString, Type type)
  {
   MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
   DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type);
   return ser.ReadObject(memoryStream);
  }
}
```